# Change the structure of a document

Tags: mongodb

I have this document structure:

```
{
    "a":{
        "b":{
            "c":"Eduardo","d":"Romero"
            }
        }
}
```

How do I get this results in mongodb language?

```
{"c":"Eduardo","d":"Romero"}
```

Thank very much in advance

Comment: Exactly with this results or in array list?

Comment: I need exactly that results. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) pipeline stage, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([ { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$a.b" } } ])
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried $replaceRoot before but I have a problem because I use mongodb 2.6.10 and that dosen't works in that version. Your solution belong to 3.4 version.